# Template class view from URL with variables in it not displaying

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I currently am trying to have this class template view render with the variabels in the URL.

For example I have `http://localhost:8000/confirm/?email=hello@example.com&conf_num=641484032777` as the URL

My class view looks like this

```
class Confirm(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'confirm.html'
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(Confirm, self).get_context()
        sub = Newsletter.objects.get(email=request.GET['email'])
        if sub.conf_num == request.GET['conf_num']:
            sub.confirmed = True
            sub.save()
            context['email'] = request.GET['email']
            context['action'] = 'added'
        else:
            context['email'] = request.GET['email']
            context['action'] = 'denied'
        return context
```

my urls.py looks like this

```
    path('confirm/', views.Confirm.as_view(), name='confirm'),
```

And my confirm.html looks like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Email Newsletter </title>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1>Email Newsletter</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">

                <p>{{ email }} has been {{ action }}.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But for some reason it never displays of updates the email or the action.  Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use `get_context_data` instead of `get_context`. So:

```
class Confirm(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'confirm.html'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(Confirm, self).get_context_data()
        sub = Newsletter.objects.get(email=self.request.GET['email'])
        if sub.conf_num == self.request.GET['conf_num']:
            sub.confirmed = True
            sub.save()
            context['email'] = self.request.GET['email']
            context['action'] = 'added'
        else:
            context['email'] = self.request.GET['email']
            context['action'] = 'denied'
        return context
```

*Note:- `self` will have its `request` attribute to get to the `GET` method. So, no need to pass `request` as argument.

Comment: Still doesn't show the action or save/confirm

Comment: Hey, can you remove the request argument from the `def get_context`.

Comment: I don't see `get_context` function in class based view, I think it should be `get_context_data` instead. I have made the change in the answer also, have a look at it.

Comment: I changed that, but now I get `KeyError: 'email'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226538/discussion-between-biplove-lamichhane-and-nadermx).